# can't trace the child of a sprite

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Maybe there's something I don't understand about the qualities of a sprite, but why does this trace as undefined? item is a movie clip and businessCard is a sprite which contains a movie clip.

```
item.addChild (businessCard);//
trace (item.businessCard);//
```

Comment: that could have many reasons. Did you try to trace businessCard? If that one is undefined, then setting another variable to the same value will naturally give the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MovieClips are dynamic, so you can create and access properties with dot notation.
Sprites are not dynamic.
To get a reference to a child, you have to access the item like this:

```
trace(item.getChildByName("businessCard").name)//traces => businessCard
```

[EDIT] I assumed that the sprite businessCard's name is "businessCard".

Comment: This response adds to the confusion. In the OP's example, businessCard is a variable name, a Sprite reference. Your code assumes that this Sprite also has its name property set to "businessCard" which is not a safe assumption to make.

Comment: Sure, I assumed the sprites name was the same as the variables name. I should have noted that you need the actual name. Even thou the method signature is quite explicit about it...

Comment: Actually, it still seems a better asumption than to guess it's index.

Comment: I agree, it's perfectly valid to set the instance's name and look it up by that name, I just wanted to call attention to the fact that the variable name and instance name are unrelated. For your 1-line code example to be guaranteed to work, you need a line of code like: businessCard.name = "businessCard";

Comment: @Adam Smit: Right, basically you need to know something about the instance you are looking for, either the index or the name. The index, thou, i feel makes more sense to use when you need to work with depths independently of the actual instance since is hard to guaranty that a certain item will remain in the same depth constantly. Either way, it was a good call!

Answer (score 1):

businessCard is a child of item, not a property. You can't access it with dot notation like that. You'll have to use something like item.getChildAt(0);

Answer (score 0):

I would make a class like this:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public dynamic class FlexSprite extends Sprite
    {
        public function FlexSprite()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And than in your code:

```
var item:FlexSprite = new FlexSprite();

//Extra Code
trace(item.bussinesCard);
```